# aerospike: unrecognized service in Docker container?

Tags: docker, aerospike

Aerospike server not starting in docker container.

installed aerospike in docker container but while trying to start service, it shows

```
aerospike: unrecognized service
```

I have used this command to start service,

```
service aerospike start
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y curl python2.7 python
RUN TEMPDIR=$(mktemp -d) && \
    cd $TEMPDIR && \
    curl -L 'aerospike.com/download/server/latest/artifact/ubuntu18' | tar xzv --strip-components 1 && \
    ./asinstall
```

Comment: Without Dockerfile it's hard to tell anything about the root casue.

Comment: FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y curl python2.7 python
RUN TEMPDIR=$(mktemp -d) && \
    cd $TEMPDIR && \
    curl -L 'https://www.aerospike.com/download/server/latest/artifact/ubuntu18' | tar xzv --strip-components 1 && \
    ./asinstall && \
    cd / && \
    rm -rf $TEMPDIR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not such service like `aerospike` in your container:

```
root@6dc95b33962b:/# service --status-all
 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
 [ - ]  procps
```

You installed `aerospike-server-community` package and as you can see this version is prepared for systemd.

```
root@eb4b937d4d45:/tmp/tmp.MIlx6iwhpg# dpkg -L  aerospike-server-community
/.
/etc
/etc/aerospike
/etc/aerospike/aerospike.conf
/etc/aerospike/irqbalance-ban.sh
/etc/aerospike/sample
/etc/aerospike/sample/README.md
/etc/aerospike/sample/aerospike_mesh.conf
/etc/aerospike/sample/aerospike_ssd.conf
/etc/aerospike/telemetry.conf
/etc/sysconfig
/etc/sysconfig/aerospike
/etc/sysconfig/aerospike_telemetry
/etc/systemd
/etc/systemd/system
/etc/systemd/system/aerospike.service.d
/etc/systemd/system/aerospike.service.d/aerospike.conf
/etc/systemd/system/aerospike.service.d/aerospike.conf.coldstart
/etc/systemd/system/aerospike.service.d/aerospike.conf.default
```

Please refer to the Stack Exchange post: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1635/is-there-any-concrete-and-acceptable-solution-for-running-systemd-inside-the-doc to learn how to run systemd within docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Usually is not a best practice to run a service within a container as you would end up having to run a different process as PID 1 and if your application crashes the container won't automatically restart or stop, giving you the false idea that everything is ok.

You should install your dependencies/application and run it within either directly in the entrypoint or within a script.

Check the official aerospike Dockerfile to see how they do it https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-server.docker/blob/c5c6355c81b03b1e7cf6d817dfc053baabd4b7b6/Dockerfile

I recommend you also read the docker documentation on best practices for building images: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/